# CSSClass not working in C# .NET

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I am not a .NET person so I have very little knowledge about .NET.  I work as ERP Implementation Consultant.  I work with C# .NET only when need be.

I am facing a strange issue with CSS on C#.

The CSS works fine on IE when I run my project via the development environment i.e. Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web.

But when I publish the project the CSS works only on Firefox but not on IE.  I have tried to give as much details as possible.  If you need any further details please let me know.

I am trying to present the production data in 24 hour clock format.  Hence the project.  All I have done is, built a table and placed text boxes in table cells.  The data gets filled in from a SQL table.  Everything works apart from visual issues.

A) TEST run via VS 2013 Web (IE 10) & Website Published on IIS8 and viewed through Firefox (34.0.5)

https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZW1v7ZuoPYebh9GWSbaaXG8auQF0oiBsAX

B) The same website viewed through IE 10

https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZQ1v7ZY3mayDOwwSmthL8fySHs18qGiguX

D)  The actual CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ActTxtBoxInTable
    {
        text-align:right;
        border:none;
        background-color:white;
        width:60px;
        font-size:x-large;
        font-weight:800;
        color:black;
    }

    .ActTxtBoxInTableLR
    {
        text-align:right;
        border:none;
        background-color:white;
        width:60px;
        font-size:x-large;
        font-weight:800;
        color:black;
    }

    .HrsTxtBoxInTable
    {
        text-align:center;
        border:none;
        background-color:navy;
        width:60px;
        font-size:x-large;
        font-weight:800;
        color:yellow;
        border-radius:6px;
    }

    .HrsTxtBoxInTableLR
    {
        text-align:center;
        border:none;
        background-color:navy;
        width:60px;
        font-size:x-large;
        font-weight:800;
        color:yellow;
        border-radius:6px;
    }
</style>
```

Thanks in advance.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Uday

Comment: hi Uday, its clear case CSS is not working for IE browser.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Kheema.  But it does work on IE 10 when I run the project through VS2013 i.e. Test Mode.  Goes pear shape after I publish!

Comment: but doesn't work when run the URL directly in IE 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this in header of html and try.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Refer [this link for Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e)

Answer (score 0):

To make everything works fine in IE, i suggest you to refer "http://css3pie.com/".

Download the `PIE.htc` and `PIE_IE678.js` from the website and add a new folder names as `pie` in your application. And in your all css classes add below two properties.

```
 behavior: url(pie/PIE.htc);
 position: relative;
```

I had few issues for my application and i got the solution by referring this.Modify and let us know if you have any issues.

Comment: Thanks for your effort.  Slightly better.  Please see the attachment.  https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZsnv7Z6YQujj8kxwYOq5KfLfnSmjTQJp7V  Thanks again for your help.